# Fail to evaluate script

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

> Fail to evaluate script: {,”name”:”MODULE_DOES_NOT_EXIST”,”message”:”Module does not exist: /lodash.min.js”,”stack”:[]}

```
/**
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 */
define([‘N/file’, ‘N/render’, ‘N/ui/serverWidget’, ‘N/search’, ‘SuiteScripts/lodash.min’],

    /**
     * @param {file} file
     * @param {render} render
     * @param {search} search
     * @param {serverWidget} serverWidget
     */
    function(file, render, serverWidget, search, _) {
        return {

            beforeLoad: function(context) {
                var item = context.newRecord;
                var form = context.form;
                var managerTemplate = file.load({
                    id: ‘SuiteScripts/template/photomanager.html’
                });
                var managerFld = form.addField({
                    id: ‘custpage_sdr_photo_manager’,
                    type: serverWidget.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
                    label: ‘Photo Selection’,
                    container: ‘store’
                });
                form.insertField({
                    field: managerFld,
                    nextfield: ‘storedisplayimage’
                });
                var compiled = _.template(managerTemplate.getContents());

                managerFld.defaultValue = compiled();
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code snippet, you need to pass the module name as a parameter in function.
Please check and let me know if this works. Also, you need to make sure that this path/file actually exists in your file cabinet : SuiteScripts/lodash.min

```js
/**
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 */
define([‘N/file’, ‘N/render’, ‘N/ui/serverWidget’, ‘N/search’, ‘SuiteScripts/lodash.min’],

    /**
     * @param {file} file
     * @param {render} render
     * @param {search} search
     * @param {serverWidget} serverWidget
     */
    function(file, render, serverWidget, search, lodash)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the lodash file would need some work in order to be recognized as a module in Netsuite.

Since you are only using lodash for template strings you can easily use native string templates which are available in SS2.1. Just change your script version

```js
/**
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 */
```

Of course given your example I suspect your manager template is more complex than a simple string replacement.

If you are embedding a dynamic page I'd recommend react.  The following snippet embeds a quite complex react app in a suitelet page:

```js
        var wrapper = form.addField({
            id:'custpage_wrapper',
            type:ui.FieldType.INLINEHTML,
            label:'na/'
        });

        var scriptFileName = 'kotn-warehouse-app.js';
        var scriptURL = getFileURL(scriptFileName);

        var cssFileName = 'kotn-warehouse.css';
        var styleURL = getFileURL(cssFileName);


        wrapper.defaultValue = '<div id="warehouse_wrap"><div id="warehouse_root"></div>\n'+
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ styleURL +'"/>\n'+
            '<script type="text/javascript" src="'+scriptURL +'"></script>'+
            '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a bad path please edit the path from 'SuiteScripts/lodash.min' to '/SuiteScripts/lodash.min'